# HPROF to do daily dumps

Tags: java, profiling, hprof

I was wondering if there's a way to "schedule" [HPROF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/samples/hprof.html) dumps so that we can have an HPROF file generated per day (or per hour depending on the size).

What I am thinking was to add profiling on the production system and have it as part of their daily reports so it becomes "routine" rather than a sudden hit because it is part of our regular process.  Sort of the idea here https://youtu.be/hnpzNAPiC0E?t=1259

Answer (score 0):

If you know the PID, you can call [jmap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/tools/jmap.html) periodically from a cron script:

```
jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=app.hprof <pid>
```

The PID could come from a PID file if available or from the output of `systemctl status <service name>` if systemd is used.

Comment: I am running in a container but at least this gives some direction.